# Re lifing the life

Tags: evolution, life

There exists nothing in this planet other than the most basic form of life : a simple bacteria, a cell like that.

It isn't the only bacteria in the world to clear things out. There are countless of them.

The question being, if they evolved incredibly fast, what sort of environment, predators, way of living and so on would be needed to remake humans ?

Basically remake life's history anyway you want up to this point.

Edit :

To put it simply, the things I'm asking are :

1. List 1 basic predator in the ages dinosaurs reigned ( in your part, it doesn't even have to be dinosaurs ) ( also explain characteristics of it )
2. List 1 basic predator in the stone age, that humans had to deal with. ( also explain characteristics of it )
3. List 1 technological advancement that you like ( it can even be from your imagination) that allowed humans to be the 'apex predator'
4. List 1 great achievement of humanity ( it can be whatever you want, in whatever age you want )
5. List 1 great historical event ( not required )
6. List 1 special part you want for humans, that hasn't happened in reality ( not required )

Although I may say 'list only one', if you wish to, you can list as many as you want, I don't  want to restrict you.
It's only the basic requirements to list 1...

I tried to lessen the scope, but it's still as broad as before, since this QUESTION is meant to be broad for those who can't understand.

Comment: That looks like the broadest question I have encountered so far. Welcome to WorldBuilding, please take the [tour](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about how this site works. We need to be able to answer a question in maybe a page or so at max. Everything else is too broad for this format. Is there something you are especially interested in? One aspect maybe? Your question might be put on hold until it fits the sites guidelines. You can edit with the little "edit"-button. Have fun!

Comment: This is definitely the winner for broadness. +1 I will devote a shrine to this question on chat. Also a vote to close, though.

Comment: xD ! At least I won in something...

Comment: Normally a question can be edited by the author and thereby applies to be reopened. For your next questions I recommend using the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on the Meta Site. There you can post your question as an answer to the Sandbox-Post and get feedback on the style, grammar, on-topic/off-topic... all this general stuff before releasing the question onto the main site. So how about we try to narrow this one down? Like - a lot. What's the most important thing you want to know?

Comment: You won't get to remake humans. Evolution is driven by many forces, and chance plays a decisive role. As [Stephen Jay Gould](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Jay_Gould) famously said, if we could rewind and then replay the tape of life the end results may well be vastly different. For example, consider what would have happened if the [Chicxulub impactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicxulub_impactor) had arrived 10 minutes later or 10 minutes earlier, missing the Earth by a few thousand kilometers...

Comment: Tl;dr : Edits will be done later |||.                  I will try to be more specific... Though I think that the beauty in this question, Lies in how broad it is. Some don't share the sentiment. I will edit the 'question' on a later date though, as I'm a bit busy now... besides I need to think what parts to edit and how, so it will still have the same meaning without being so broad. As I made the question, it isn't broad to me, but no one thinks the same and yea... it is broad to others, since they don't know what I though before making the question.

Comment: Marios this is an interesting mental exercise but is not a good fit for the format of the site.  I have voted to leave it closed.  Please check out the [help] for guidance on writing good questions and answers.

Comment: At this point I can't edit it more, without breaking what I originally asked.

Comment: After the edit I don't think it still needs to be on hold, as the subject of my question is clearly specified. Please state a reason of why it doesn't fit the format of the site after the edits... I swear I have seen one similar 'question' to mines, that wasn't putted on hold ( not exactly a similar as there were a lot of differences, but the structure I remember was similar. Also I don't remember what it was, since I don't  have photographic memory, and I hope that this doesn't make my words less credible ).

Comment: I just want to see answers of other ppl... if only I had 3000 reputation points I would vote it to be released from on hold... at the very least, tell me how to 'fix' the format, so as it will be more to 'your' liking

Answer (score 2):

Well, the short answer:  https://xkcd.com/1123/ (Hydrogen + Time).

That said, you get huge speedups by providing a few multicellular organisms.  Mostly you need to toss an Evolvo-6000 at the planet.

---

The Evolvo-6000 is the perfect tool for reseeding those pesky failed experiments.  It takes a huge biome adjusted your wasteland to really get going, and why wait eons for a few cosmic ways to make the Biome.   The Evolvo-6000 takes what it can find from a atmospheric and soil sampling and nudges, well shoves, evolution into high gear.   Modify a bacteria that thrives on sequestering carbon dioxide and methane to bring that atmosphere back in line?  Done.  Need an evolutionary dead end to break down leftover plastics?  Done.   In each case, a new organism is released with significant advantages so that it can conquer its environmental niche.   Hybridization and natural selection will push those traits through the entire world.   Most planets bloom with intelligent life within a century.

The Evolvo-6000 is a fully self-operated, hard landing capable, mobile evolutionary biology device.  Payment plans and planetary mortgage financing are available, so talk to a dealer now!  Also check out our line of planetary accumulators and deaccumulators to adjust your gravity.

Evolvo.   Because Life Can't Wait.